# Работа с canvas и fullscreen mod

Tags: javascript, canvas

Доброго времени суток уважаемые знатоки!
Есть некоторая неопределенность при с canvas и fullscreen...
Есть следующий код:

```js
function app_start()
{
  canvas = document.getElementById('app_canvas');
  window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
}

function mouese_click(e)
{
 full_screen();
}

function full_screen()
{
  if(canvas.requestFullscreen)
    {
      canvas.requestFullscreen();
    }
    else if(canvas.webkitRequestFullscreen)
    {
      canvas.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } 
    else if(canvas.mozRequestFullscreen)
    {
      canvas.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }
}

function resize(e)
{
 if (is_fullscreen)
 {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
 }
 else
 {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 22;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 22;
 }
}
```

```css
#app_canvas:-webkit-full-screen {
 height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body onload="app_start();">
 <canvas id="app_canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

Все вроде как просто, есть кнопка, мы на неё нажимаем и переводим canvas в fullscreen mod. И вот тут наступают проблемы:

1) Если использовать CSS и задавать размеры 100% :

```
* canvas не увеличивается, а растягивается, что приводит к "растяжению" всех элементов canvas. Что не круто... хотелось бы только размер canvas увеличить.

* Отрабатывает только увеличение по высоте, по ширине не срабатывает, но если задавать конкретными значениями то работает.
```

2) Если увеличивать размер canvas через задание высоты и ширины на прямую.

```
* Если то не fullscreen mod то при задании размеров window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight размеры превышают размеры окна и появляются скролы, что то же не круто, и по этому появляется магическое число 22 которое просто подогнано под конкретный случай, что тоже не круто.
```

Может кто знает как решить эти неопределенности с fullscreen mod для canvas "красиво"?